# If f and g are inverses of each other, using the chain rule show $f′(x)= {1 \over g′(f(x))}$.

Tags: calculus, analysis

Use the chain rule to show that if f and g are inverses of each other then:
$f′(x)= {1 \over g′(f(x))}$.

I know that I have to use $ g(f(x)) = x$, but I am not really sure where to start.

Answer (score 1):

$g(f)=x\implies \dfrac{d(g(f))}{dx}=1 \implies \dfrac{d(g(f))}{df}\cdot \dfrac{df}{dx}=1 \implies f'=\dfrac{1}{g'(f)}$